# Problems with TortoiseSVN ignore folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I selected a folder called build, and i selected ignore (recursivelly) to ignore the folder and all his subfiles.

The problem is that now, all the folders called build are ignored in my project, and these folders are not subfolders of the original build folder...

Why has happened this? how can i show a list of all the ignores of my project and how to cancel all the ignores and repeat them correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to bahrep

> Why has happened this?

Because it was result of your operation and your misinterpretation of "how ignore and recursive ignore work"

When you'll ignore `PATTERN`, which pattern have to be added to the **parent node**, and if ignore recursively - ignore-pattern exactly repeated in all subdirs of directory-of-definition

In your case, in assumption of existence `ROOT/build`, you ignore of build wrote svn:ignore to the root-dir and recursiveness propagated to the whole tree, unrelated to `/build` root-node

> how can i show a list of all the ignores of my project

Better - in CLI
In the root of project `svn pl -v -R` will show exact full list of **all** properties

> how to cancel all the ignores and repeat them correctly?

TortoiseSVN -> Properies

Edit or delete existing `svn:ignore`

> repeat them correctly?

If your business-task is "Ignore `build` directory in root and it's subtree only without other `build` directories in tree" it will be current ignore pattern (non-recursive "build" in root)

Answer (score 0):

> Why has happened this? how can i show a list of all the ignores of my
>   project and how to cancel all the ignores and repeat them correctly?

1. Right-click in your working copy,
2. TortoiseSVN | Properties,
3. Modify `svn:ignore` property and select "Apply property recursively" option.

For more information, read [TortoiseSVN manual | Project Settings](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-props).

Comment: what will happen if i do this?

Comment: You asked *how can i show a list of all the ignores of my project and how to cancel all the ignores and repeat them correctly?*. That's what it will do.